# sql syntax error - not sure why am getting this?

Tags: mysql

i can't figure this out, for some reason im getting this error message:

```
Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND ptb_block_user.blocked=1' at line 5
```

and this is my mysql query, don't know what the problem is, please can someone help me?

```
function blocked_users() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT * 
                        FROM ptb_block_user
                        WHERE ptb_block_user.blocked_id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND ptb_block_user.user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']."
                        AND ptb_block_user.blocked='1' ";
                        $blocked_users = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($blocked_users);
            return $blocked_users;

        }
```

Comment: You need single quotes around the $_SESSION var I think, so `AND ptb_block_user.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'`

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a `print $query` too see how your SQL query looks like. It will be easier to spot the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
function blocked_users() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT * 
                        FROM ptb_block_user
                        WHERE ptb_block_user.blocked_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($profile_id)."
                        AND ptb_block_user.user_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."
                        AND ptb_block_user.blocked=1;";
            $blocked_users = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($blocked_users);
            return $blocked_users;
        }
```

**Use MySqli lib instead of MySql : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ptb_block_user b
 WHERE b.blocked_id = '$profile_id' 
   AND b.user_id = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}' 
   AND b.blocked=1
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you use plain php and no framework, sou should alway use prepared statements for mysql communication. This is much more secure and protects you from mysql injection.

Try this.

```
db = new mysqli("your_ip_or_host","username","password","name_of_database");
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * 
                    FROM ptb_block_user
                    WHERE ptb_block_user.blocked_id = ?
                    AND ptb_block_user.user_id = ?
                    AND ptb_block_user.blocked=?");

$st->bind_param('iii', intval($profile_id), intval($_SESSION['user_id']),1);

$st->execute();

$st->store_result();
$st->bind_result($col1, $col2, ... , $colx);

while($st->fetch())
{
    echo "col1=$col, col2=$col2, ...., colX=$colx \n";
}

$st->close();
```